# How to change date format in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am facing same problem, by using above mentioned code problem is still not resolved.
My date is coming in JSON like
 `200515`

```
where 20= date
      05= month
      15= year,
```

I am using the following code:-

```
{{200515 | date : "EEE, MMM dd"}}
```

but it gives me:

```
Thu, jan 01
```

but I want

```
Wed, May 20
```

Please help for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.substring()` to parse your date string and build a new date object. This works with angular's date filter.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  var date = '200515',
      day = date.substring(0, 2),
      month = date.substring(2, 4),
      year = date.substring(4, 6),
      time = '0513',
      hour = time.substring(0, 2),
      minute = time.substring(2, 4);
  $scope.date = new Date('20' + year, month - 1, day, hour, minute);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp", ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{date | date : "hh:mm EEE, MMM dd"}}
</div>
```

Comment: and what to do with time if JSON gives me time like:
0513 where 05-hours and 13-minutes

Comment: you mean at the end of the string? Like this: `2005150513`?

Comment: no its a separate value but I want to show like05:13

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a date object before using your filter because it will only formatted the date. Here your date is null.

Firstly you have to create your date using basic Date api

`new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);`

and after use the created object in your code with the filter

Answer (score 0):

Your input string for your date 200015 is not a valid ISO 8601 date string. You must supply either a javascript Date object or a valid string of format such as 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ' or 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ' etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601